# Enable/disable group of multiple extension in VS Code in single click

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to make list of extensions to enable disable in one click at a time.

Comment: Sounds like someone already implemented an extension with similar functionality, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15466#issuecomment-864458604